# Como usar strings como parâmetros no R

Tags: string, r, dplyr, eval

Galera,

Preciso criar uma coluna usando uma string e usar outras strings colunas como argumentos, por exemplo:

```
dataframe <- dataframe %>% mutate("Newstring" = case_when("stringA" < 65 & stringB == 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
```

Eu acredito que parse ou eval, ou até mesmo a combinação das duas, possa ajudar nessa tarefa.

Podem ajudar?

Atenciosamente,
Arduin

Comment: `get("stringA")` funciona. Quanto a `"Newstring"`, creio que só mudando o nome da coluna *a posteriori*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O melhor lugar para entender como faz para usar strings no lugar de nomes de variáveis é esse documento [*Programming with dplyr*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html).

É necessário fazer algo muito parecido com `parse` e `eval` que você citou, mas o `dplyr`, fornece por meio do pacote `rlang`, uma forma mais intuitiva. Vale a pena ler também o [site do `rlang`](http://rlang.r-lib.org).

Suponha que você tenha duas strings representando nomes de variáveis:

```
x <- "nova_coluna"
y <- "hp"
```

Você pode criar uma nova coluna chamada `nova_coluna` que é igual a variável `hp` da seguinte forma:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

y <- sym(y)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(!! x := !!y)
```

Note que não usamos `=`, pois `!!x = !!y` não é um código sintaticamente válido. Usamos a função `sym` para transformar uma string em um símbolo, para que o dplyr encarasse como um nome de variável.